# Is it possible to Sync Project with Grade Files without the app tree closing?

Tags: android, android-studio

As the title says, I'd like to know if it possible to Sync Project with Grade Files in Android Studio without the "app tree" closing, as I'm making an app and I need to Sync the files for to allow the app to run, and when this happens, the project tree closes, and I have to open it all again... Its a bit annoying and for that reason, I made this post.

Thanks everyone, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it.

The tree isn't just "closing," it's being completely rebuilt. When you sync your project files, Android Studio also has to re-index everything, as part of that process.